# How to 'smooth' 3D bar charts?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I plan to display the altitude of each city in France using a 3D projection. By doing so, I would be able to see a relief map of France.

When I do so with my values here is what I get :
[image: The 3D plot I've got]

**I was wondering if it is possible to smooth the bars to appear more like a surface and if it is possible to change the `colormap` to have colors that match better with a relief map**

Here is the values (there are quite a lot, but with less values, we can't plot anything interesting) :

```
import numpy as np

latitude = np.array([45.7333, 45.75, 46.25, 46.1167, 49.6333, 49.25, 49.85, 49.4333, 49.9833, 49.8333, 49.9167, 49.8833, 49.5333, 49.5333, 46.2833, 46.0667, 46.1, 46.1833, 46.15, 46.1667, 44.4167, 44.0833, 44.3923, 44.6667, 44.65, 43.65, 43.8833, 44.8167, 45.0667, 45.2333, 44.3667, 50.1, 42.9167, 42.65, 43.0, 43.15, 43.0, 43.0833, 48.2667, 48.0333, 48.2667, 48.3833, 43.0853, 43.25, 42.9833, 43.2167, 44.1, 44.15, 44.4667, 43.8333, 49.2114, 49.0, 48.85, 49.1167, 49.0312, 49.2167, 49.3167, 49.2667,48.85, 48.9167, 49.15, 45.15, 45.3167, 45.6, 45.4333, 45.3931, 45.6667, 45.6333, 45.7531, 45.8, 45.9667, 45.0333, 47.3167, 47.1833, 47.6, 47.1167, 48.4333, 48.45, 46.2833, 45.8975, 45.8667, 44.9667, 45.3833, 44.7333, 44.8333, 44.7833, 45.3167, 47.2167, 47.1333, 47.45, 46.95, 47.3167, 47.0333, 47.4833, 47.4, 47.3333, 44.6167, 44.5667, 44.6833, 44.7667, 44.55, 44.75, 49.3667, 48.7667, 49.2333, 49.2667, 49.2167, 49.1667, 48.5167, 48.4167, 48.0167, 44.15, 44.15, 44.2, 44.05, 42.8167, 43.45, 43.75, 43.45, 43.7333, 43.7167, 43.0964, 43.6333, 43.4333, 43.9583,43.5828, 43.6333, 43.4289, 44.85, 44.4, 44.6167, 45.3275, 44.3833, 43.7333, 43.4684, 43.7945, 43.5333, 48.6333, 47.8667, 46.3867, 47.35, 47.2667, 47.0333, 44.9833, 47.2167, 46.4167, 46.6167, 47.1833, 46.8, 46.7667, 43.8833, 43.6167, 46.2, 46.1706, 45.5333, 45.7833, 45.1833, 45.3, 47.0667, 47.4417, 47.0556, 47.3333, 47.2, 48.2667, 48.05, 48.0333, 47.8333, 47.85, 48.1667, 47.8667, 44.65, 44.4667, 44.45, 44.4167, 44.3, 44.4667, 44.3, 47.3333, 47.2833, 49.3, 48.7667, 48.7333, 49.3, 48.8, 49.0167, 48.6, 49.1167, 48.8, 49.3333, 48.5333, 49.05, 48.7395, 48.95,49.0667, 47.9998, 48.0333, 47.7333, 47.9333, 48.4167, 48.4203, 48.5423, 48.0167, 48.4667, 48.5, 49.3333, 48.6833, 49.097, 48.5833, 47.8167, 47.85, 49.3333, 49.0667, 49.1667, 49.3833, 48.95, 49.0333, 48.7833, 48.85, 48.8833, 49.0333, 47.4028, 47.4333, 47.4, 47.2833, 47.4167, 50.6167, 50.7, 50.6667, 50.05, 50.8667, 50.25, 49.5833, 49.6333, 49.4, 49.6, 49.5, 49.2167, 49.6, 48.7, 48.85, 48.55, 48.4833, 48.8, 50.6167, 50.8167, 50.2126, 50.8, 50.5333, 50.2833, 50.95, 50.9, 50.35, 50.1667, 50.8, 50.4167, 50.2, 46.2, 45.6667, 45.8833, 45.4167, 43.45, 43.4333, 43.3833, 43.2667, 43.3333, 43.2167, 42.7667, 42.7167, 42.6333, 48.7667, 48.9333, 48.5667, 48.95, 48.6859, 48.8139, 48.95, 46.1833, 45.5606, 45.6333, 47.65, 47.4667, 47.75, 47.8, 47.5167, 47.6167, 47.7667, 47.4333, 46.6333, 47.0073, 46.8167, 46.3, 46.8, 46.8167, 47.762, 48.3498, 47.9673, 48.1333, 48.3333, 45.55, 45.6667,45.55, 45.2167, 46.0833, 46.4, 46.3167, 46.1167, 46.3, 46.0667, 49.7, 49.5667, 49.6, 49.8333, 49.7167, 49.85, 49.3833, 49.5667, 49.8167, 48.5167, 49.0667, 48.4167, 48.45, 48.7333, 48.8667, 48.3645, 48.45, 48.9833, 48.7039, 48.8833, 46.55, 46.2, 46.4167, 46.1167, 49.9, 50.1, 49.9333, 49.5833, 50.0333, 50.15, 49.9833, 50.2333, 50.0, 50.0667, 50.0167, 49.7, 44.25, 43.5, 44.1167, 43.8333, 46.7833, 46.75, 46.3333, 46.9364, 45.75, 48.25, 48.2833, 48.3667, 48.3333, 48.35, 48.25, 48.1667, 47.9833, 47.5, 48.2167, 47.8833, 47.75, 47.4833, 48.6667, 48.8667, 48.75,49.1, 49.0, 48.9833, 48.9833, 49.0, 42.2189, 42.7, 42.5742, 42.4573]) 


longitude = np.array([5.65, 5.75, 4.85, 4.86667, 3.85, 3.53333, 3.23333, 3.3, 3.21667, 3.9, 3.25, 3.2, 3.25, 3.16667, 3.6, 3.51667, 3.36667, 3.53333, 3.0, 3.3, 6.73333, 5.65, 6.62778, 6.65, 6.13333, 6.86667, 7.01667, 4.76667, 4.68333, 4.58333, 4.65, 4.76667, 1.68333, 1.83333, 1.05, 1.51667, 1.35, 1.36667, 3.81667, 4.43333, 3.65, 3.65, 2.70056, 1.96667, 2.19167, 1.83333, 2.9, 3.1, 2.71667, 4.95, -0.513889, 0.15, -0.233333, -0.083333, -0.422778, -0.533333, 0.033333, -0.483333, -0.766667, -0.483333, -0.216667, 2.93333, 2.58333, 0.35, -0.033333, -0.0727778, 0.5, -0.516667, -0.506111, -0.216667, -0.716667, 1.8, 5.11667, 5.28333, 4.26667, 4.6, -2.96667, -3.31667, 2.21667, 1.82111, 1.8, 0.933333, 0.716667, 0.533333, 1.2, 1.0, 0.6, 6.55, 6.8, 6.41667, 6.45, 6.4, 6.13333, 6.83333, 6.63333, 5.9, 5.08333, 5.16667, 4.95,4.98333, 4.85, 5.26667, 1.38333, 1.1, 0.9, 0.916667, 0.55, 0.7, 1.75, 1.48333, -4.56667, 3.68333, 4.68333, 4.53333, 4.7, 0.55, 1.73333, 1.11667, 1.06667, 1.41667, 1.56667, 0.625833, 0.35, 0.466667, 0.141667, 0.614167, 0.066667, 0.415, -0.25, -0.05, -0.066667, -0.575833, -0.216667, 4.08333, 3.17889, 3.91445, 3.93333, -2.06667, -1.88333, 1.30722, 0.466667, 0.6, 0.45, 5.88333, 5.68333, 5.46667, 5.7,5.61667, 5.83333, 6.0, -0.733333, -0.566667, 4.38333, 3.855, 3.98333, 3.85, 3.9, 3.65, -1.31667, -1.425, 0.487223, -2.43333, -1.75, 2.23333, 2.4, 2.8, 1.7, 2.93333, 2.28333, 2.23333, 1.43333, 1.23333, 0.183333, 1.05, 3.31667, 3.7, 3.18333,-0.666667, -0.983333, -1.63333, -1.23333, -1.38333, -1.56667, -1.4, -1.55, -1.08333, 3.8, 4.26667, 3.76667, 3.83333, 4.78333, 4.31139, 3.61667, 4.2, 5.49834, 4.8, 5.1, 5.86667, 5.21667, -0.1325, -0.206944, -0.4, 6.23333, 6.1, 5.75, 6.38333, 5.59278, 5.63333, -2.5, -3.0, 6.11667, 6.61667, 6.03333, 6.31667, 6.85, 6.38333, 6.46667, 6.78333, 6.86667, 6.2, 3.40028, 3.5, 3.6, 3.4, 3.58333, 3.01667, 2.4, 3.23333, 3.93333, 2.28333, 3.53333, 2.5, 2.03333, 1.88333, 1.93333, 1.8, 2.66667, 2.6, -0.316667, 0.6, 0.3, 0.85, -0.7, 2.36667, 1.9, 2.53056, 2.0, 1.93333, 2.91667, 2.01667, 1.83333, 2.6, 2.56667, 2.1, 2.81667, 2.78333, 2.75, 3.63333, 2.91667, 3.38333, -0.3, -1.55, -0.9, -0.683333, 0.133333, 0.433333, 2.63333, 2.53333, 2.95, 7.95, 7.83333, 7.43333, 7.71667, 7.44945, 7.53028, 7.8, 4.55, 4.80612,4.6, 6.23333, 6.28333, 6.48333, 6.33333, 6.48333, 6.3, 5.78333, 5.56667, 5.18333, 4.47139, 4.88333, 4.83333, 4.6, 4.96667, 0.655278, 0.254722, -0.137778, 0.716667, 0.083333, 6.21667, 5.91667, 5.91667, 6.23333, 6.43333, 6.6, 6.3, 6.28333, 6.78333, 6.6, 1.25, 1.66667, 0.133333, 1.15, 0.666667, 0.65, 0.883333, 1.11667, 0.8, 3.16667, 2.6, 2.95, 2.55, 2.63333, 3.35, 2.98834, 2.83333, 1.66667, 1.98417,1.71667, -0.483333, -0.316667, -0.35, -0.166667, 1.83333, 1.65, 2.71667, 2.65, 1.5, 1.96667, 2.91667, 1.66667, 2.75, 1.83333, 2.2, 2.35, 1.13333, 5.73333, 5.1,5.21667, -1.43333, -1.91667, 0.2, 0.605833, 1.11667, 6.08333, 6.16667, 5.43333,6.33333, 6.43333, 6.41667, 7.01667, 5.91667, 3.81667, 3.06667, 3.95, 3.41667, 6.91667, 2.53333, 2.43333, 2.46667, 2.45, 2.33333, 2.35, 2.2, 2.38333, 9.3714, 9.44945, 9.0089, 9.34334]) 


altitude = np.array([495.0, 623.0, 212.0, 267.0, 116.0, 140.0, 128.0, 156.0, 146.0, 208.0, 129.0, 123.0, 76.0, 76.0, 342.0, 608.0, 375.0, 482.0, 729.0, 343.0, 3027.0, 1430.0, 2879.0, 2694.0, 1340.0, 790.0, 1108.0, 535.0, 486.0, 912.0, 415.0, 355.0, 1093.0, 2840.0, 1247.0, 383.0, 931.0, 580.0, 235.0, 333.0, 263.0, 186.0, 344.0, 346.0, 602.0, 360.0, 1087.0, 846.0, 711.0, 67.0, 72.0, 186.0, 229.0, 50.0, 186.0, 77.0, 112.0, 59.0, 246.0, 261.0, 22.0, 1169.0, 980.0, 204.0, 162.0, 166.0, 284.0, 52.0, 89.0, 97.0, 28.0, 366.0, 251.0, 204.0, 387.0, 452.0, 254.0, 287.0, 656.0, 798.0,741.0, 229.0, 208.0, 197.0, 218.0, 219.0, 192.0, 943.0, 1087.0, 470.0, 1171.0, 561.0, 690.0, 417.0, 592.0, 251.0, 651.0, 1088.0, 485.0, 415.0, 210.0, 1000.0, 140.0, 179.0, 177.0, 142.0, 171.0, 157.0, 156.0, 157.0, 79.0, 1200.0, 268.0, 359.0, 261.0, 2676.0, 262.0, 274.0, 331.0, 175.0, 225.0, 515.0, 222.0, 302.0, 181.0,285.0, 204.0, 286.0, 77.0, 152.0, 83.0, 90.0, 133.0, 92.0, 150.0, 241.0, 3.0, 56.0, 100.0, 237.0, 101.0, 98.0, 123.0, 2856.0, 353.0, 563.0, 590.0, 391.0, 678.0, 804.0, 57.0, 136.0, 721.0, 595.0, 1236.0, 900.0, 948.0, 1145.0, 54.0, 52.0, 39.0, 60.0, 27.0, 137.0, 142.0, 127.0, 113.0, 203.0, 129.0, 131.0, 394.0, 332.0, 77.0, 263.0, 1012.0, 1699.0, 1005.0, 104.0, 146.0, 41.0, 205.0, 120.0, 44.0, 134.0, 43.0, 117.0, 243.0, 177.0, 193.0, 85.0, 197.0, 230.0, 231.0, 132.0, 458.0, 358.0, 486.0, 332.0, 390.0, 393.0, 360.0, 116.0, 340.0, 319.0, 327.0, 269.0, 391.0, 381.0, 156.0, 137.0, 232.0, 406.0, 362.0, 310.0, 261.0, 314.0, 313.0, 275.0, 249.0, 237.0, 289.0, 217.0, 299.0, 384.0, 280.0, 49.0, 76.0, 43.0, 217.0, 63.0, 107.0, 127.0, 192.0, 234.0, 186.0, 198.0, 102.0, 102.0, 270.0, 261.0, 203.0, 237.0, 211.0, 62.0, 181.0, 178.0, 173.0, 192.0, 99.0, 5.0, 59.0, 131.0, 168.0, 116.0, 66.0, 108.0, 597.0, 663.0, 994.0, 767.0, 250.0, 94.0, 145.0, 266.0, 245.0, 563.0, 423.0, 800.0, 28.0, 128.0, 199.0, 273.0, 262.0, 290.0, 275.0, 446.0, 1004.0,548.0, 929.0, 400.0, 313.0, 340.0, 312.0, 375.0, 447.0, 372.0, 238.0, 209.0, 530.0, 191.0, 347.0, 438.0, 206.0, 153.0, 210.0, 109.0, 200.0, 152.0, 656.0, 1513.0, 576.0, 3464.0, 1843.0, 770.0, 520.0, 931.0, 2430.0, 1197.0, 207.0, 191.0, 105.0, 138.0, 128.0, 120.0, 129.0, 176.0, 103.0, 161.0, 157.0, 123.0, 132.0, 107.0,203.0, 108.0, 117.0, 128.0, 178.0, 174.0, 228.0, 89.0, 116.0, 115.0, 157.0, 90.0, 122.0, 126.0, 123.0, 117.0, 152.0, 5.0, 135.0, 87.0, 134.0, 158.0, 270.0, 872.0, 453.0, 693.0, 84.0, 19.0, 154.0, 127.0, 331.0, 445.0, 392.0, 441.0, 382.0, 383.0, 377.0, 1302.0, 339.0, 346.0, 169.0, 278.0, 292.0, 575.0, 89.0, 117.0, 88.0, 101.0, 186.0, 123.0, 170.0, 147.0, 735.0, 963.0, 1163.0, 1236.0])
```

And here is the code I've done to plot the 3D bar charts :

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl


z=np.ones(len(longitude))

dx=np.ones(len(longitude))
dy=np.ones(len(latitude))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')


cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('jet')
norm=Normalize(vmin=min(np.array(altitude)),vmax=max(np.array(altitude)))
colors=cmap(norm(np.array(altitude)))

bars=ax.bar3d(longitude,latitude,z,dx,dy,altitude, color=colors,shade=False)

ax.set_title('Relief', weight='bold')

ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
plt.show()
```

**EDIT 1:**
Thanks to the reply of @JohanC, I changed the `colormap` to terrain and it is perfect.

I also tried to use `ax.plot_trisurf(longitude, latitude, altitude, cmap='terrain')`instead of `ax.bar3d(longitude,latitude,z,dx,dy,altitude, color=colors,shade=False)` as I have a better visualisation but it is not perfect especially with borders. Here is what I have :
[image: The result I got with plot_trisurf]

**Is there a way to remove some of the triangles automatically to shape better with the real French territory ?**

Comment: Did you try `ax.plot_trisurf(longitude, latitude, altitude, cmap='terrain')`?  Note that this will calculate a triangulation, with the shape of the convex hull of the x and y positions.

Comment: @JohanC It works perfectly for the `cmap` but for the triangulation, it is better than bar charts but we can't really see the borders. To see how it looks like, I've edited my question

Comment: The coast- and borderlines are not in the data, so you can not expect to see them in the plot. You would have to add more points along the border to your dataset first. I think a few along the Atlantic and Channel coastlines would already improve the shape a lot. You can of course set their altitude to zero. In any case, Corsica should be plotted separately, to avoid the distortion in the southeast.

Comment: Thanks @Arne I removed Corsica
But for adding more points, the problem is that I can't easily change the data from my lists